# I want to indicate in the status line whether or not `spell` is set

Tags: vimscript, spell-checking, statusline

I am using `vim-tinyline` and it doesn't seem to have an option for this and I have no idea how to write a function to do this.

Example function from tinyline that checks whether the file has been modified:

```
function! TlModified() " {{{                                        
  " Make sure we ignore &modified when choosewin is active          

  let choosewin = exists('g:choosewin_active') && g:choosewin_active
  return &modified && ! choosewin ? ' ⚫' : ''                      
endfunction
```

This one returns a `⚫` if the file has been modified. How would I do something similar if `spell` is set?

Comment: Just replace `&modified` with `&spell`?

Comment: now I feel dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user Carpetsmoker above in the comments it was really simple, this is what I ended up with:

```
function! TlSpell() " {{{ 
  " Returns spell state   
  return &spell ? '⚫' : ''
endfunction
```